# Accurate method to track time

Tags: c#, time, timer, duration, stopwatch

For my application, I've to track the time change, to "smooth" the time change.

A system time change can occurs for several reasons:

- The user change its system time
- The OS NTP Server updates the local time
- ...

So actually we have a "TimeProvider", which provide to the whole application the current time.

The goal is to detect if a time shift occurs and correct our local time smoothly(like, if we have a "time jump" of one hour, correct 100ms every second until this is fully corrected).

Here is basically what I've to provide the time(please note that currently I absolutely don't smooth the time change, but not my current issue)

```
internal class TimeChange : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly Stopwatch _watch = new Stopwatch();
    private DateTime _currentTime;

    public DateTime CurrentTime 
    {
        get { return _currentTime + _watch.Elapsed; }
    }

    public TimeChange()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
        _watch.Start();
        _currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Elapsed -= OnTimerElapsed;
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan timeDerivation = currentTime - _currentTime - _watch.Elapsed;
        _watch.Restart();
        _currentTime = currentTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Derivation: " + timeDerivation.TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
}
```

But when doing some test, I noticed that I've differences even without doing anything on my local time. Not huge differences(<1ms), but still:

```
Press enter to stop
Derivation: -0.1367ms
Derivation: 0.9423ms
Derivation: 0.0437ms
Derivation: 0.0617ms
Derivation: 0.0095ms
Derivation: 0.0646ms
Derivation: -0.0149ms
```

And this is derivation for 1 second, if I just replace the 1000ms by 10000ms, I quickly have a time derivation between 1ms and 0.5ms.

So my question(Finally :P):

1. Why between two `Utc.DateTime` gave me so much differences? They are both based on clock Tick no?
2. Isn't there a way to get this time shift more precisely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No they are not both based on clock tick. `Stopwatch` maybe either high or low res. If low res, then it uses `DateTime.UtcNow` underneith. Unfortuantely you cannot choose if it's high or low, so:
2. Create own "Stopwatch" that always uses `DateTime.UtcNow` underneith.

**EDIT**

That's a stupid suggestion in (2.), you obviously need to avoid `DateTime.UtcNow` as that's what you are trying to correct. I suggest you look at working in ticks, by which I mean 1/10000 of a second, to match high-res `Stopwatch`. This is because `TimeSpan` is only accurate to 1/1000 of a second.

Number 1. in more detail:

`Stopwatch` uses this method:

```
public static long GetTimestamp()
{
    if (!Stopwatch.IsHighResolution)
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return utcNow.Ticks; //There are 10,000 of these ticks in a second
    }
    else
    {
        long num = (long)0;
        SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(out num);
        return num; //These ticks depend on the processor, and
                    //later will be converted to 1/10000 of a second
    }
}
```

But like I say, `IsHighResolution` appears to be not settable and as a `static` applies system wide anyway, so write your own.

Comment: I checked, `StopWatch.IsHighResolution` is `True` which allows me to have a small difference between the DateTime.UtcNow and the time measurements using the stopwatch. But is this difference expected?

Comment: Yes. As I understand it `DateTime.UtcNow` is querying a clock on your PC, and `QueryPerformanceCounter` is querying the processor. Not got any proof yet though...

Comment: This might answer it http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622002/low-resolution-stopwatch-behaves-incorrectly Found by googling "Datetime vs QueryPerformanceCounter" may be better info out there somewhere.